# rsync copying directory contents non-recursively

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to copy the contents of a series of directories non-recursively to another remote system.

```
/dirA/dir1/file
/dirA/dir2/file
/dirA/dir3/file
```

dir1, dir2, and dir3 contain many directories that I **do not** want copied. Copy on the remote host to /dirB maintaining the same directory structure.

I tried:

```
rsync /dirA/*/ host:/dirB/
rsync /dirA/   host:/dirB/
```

But they don't do what I want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

rsync allows you to specify patterns that trigger the inclusion or exclusion of files and directories. I think you want to use something like this:

```
rsync -a -f '- /*/*/' /dirA/ host:/dirB/
```

Explanation:

- `-a` triggers the archive mode that activates both recursion and preservation of "symbolic links, devices, attributes, permissions, ownerships, etc.", according to [`man rsync`](https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).
- `-f` is short for `--filter=`, which adds a file-filtering rule.

  - The pattern is inside single quotes so that the shell does not expand wildcards; double quotes would work equally well in this case.
  - `-`  means this is an exclude pattern.
  - The leading `/` means the pattern must start at `dirA/` (the rsync "transfer-root").
  - The `*/*` part of the pattern refers to anything inside of a subdirectory.
  - The trailing `/` limits the exclusion to directories. Files inside a subdirectory of `dirA/` are not affected.

So in the end, rsync copies nothing more than one level down (and also does not create second-level directories).

Comment: Very nice! I was able to use `-f '- /*/'` to restrict to top level files only. I also had to specify `-f '- .*'` to exclude dot files, since I was syncing a home directory.

Answer (score 6):

The solution above (by PleaseStand) didn't work for me for some reason. This worked though:

`rsync -avc --no-r ./source/* ./destination/`

There's also this alternative one:

`rsync -avc --exclude "/" ./source/ ./destination/`

Answer (score 1):

One of the "features" of rsync is how directories are parsed.

`rsync /dirA/   host:/dirB/`
and 
`rsync /dirA   host:/dirB`
should theoretically be equivalent.

As not wanting to encourage recursiveness, you want to avoid `-r`, `-a` which in addition to other things implies `-r`.

I'm still not quite done with research, but this is my starting answer.